# How can I fix Backup and sync from Google from causing a delay when opening Quick Access folders?

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

As seen [here](https://streamable.com/36onq0), Backup and sync from Google is causing a large delay in opening my Quick Access folders even when nothing is being synced. How can I fix this? I don't think my system is being bottlenecked considering I have a Samsung 960 EVO, 16 gb of RAM, and an Intel Core i5 7600K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was found to be caused by the Google Drive context menu. Removing it by following these [steps](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/158948-how-add-remove-google-drive-context-menu-windows.html) fixed it for me.